# Async function of the Dart programming language is not working properly

Tags: asynchronous, dart

I couldn't figure out why the following code didn't work correctly.
I also tried it on DartPad. The result is the same.

```
import 'dart:async';

Future<bool> longWait(String prefix) async {
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    print('$prefix $i');
  }
  return true;
}

Future testAsync() async {
  print('starting');
  longWait('Async');
  print('done');
}

main(List<String> arguments) {
  testAsync();
}
```

```
the result is:
starting
Async 0
Async 1
Async 2
Async 3
Async 4
done

but it has to be this:
starting
done
Async 0
Async 1
Async 2
Async 3
Async 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Dart 2 sync code at the beginning of async functions is executed sync.
This was different in Dart 1.

A workaround would be

```
Future<bool> longWait(String prefix) async {
  await Future.microtask((){});

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    print('$prefix $i');
  }
  return true;
}
```

The code after the `await` is executed async and results in the desired behavior. (tested in DartPad)

Comment: Yeah, It's very good, thanks a lot.

I've looked a bit after your response. 
This process has changed a lot in Dart2. 

You don't need to write "Future<bool> or Future" at the beginning of the longWait()  function and do not need to write - import 'dart:async' - at the top. Just adding one line ( await Future.microtask((){}); )

Its still working for this example.

Comment: The return type `Future<bool>` was optional in Dart 1 as well, but `Future` and `Stream` are now exported by `dart:core` since Dart 2.1 and therefore always available.